# how can set edit text as output and input?

Tags: android, button, android-edittext

I'd like to know how to have multiple *EditText*, detect if one of those were modified and calculate the value to set txt of the not modified *EditText* in relation with the other.
It should be like a formula solver: 4 *EditText* 1 *Button*.

When you press the button if one of the *EditText* is empty the text of the empty one has to be set to a value obtained with the value of the others. Actually it seems not to work, the activity crush when I press the calculate button.

```
public class motolineare extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    EditText et1;
    EditText et2;
    EditText et3;
    EditText et4;

    Button calculate;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.formula);
        TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        textView1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
        et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);
        et3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et3);
        et4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et4);

        calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);

        calculate.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double num1 = 0;
        double num2 = 0;
        double num3 = 0;
        double num4 = 0;
        double res = 0;

        if ((TextUtils.isEmpty(et1.getText().toString()) & TextUtils
                .isEmpty(et2.getText().toString()))
                || ((TextUtils.isEmpty(et1.getText().toString()) & TextUtils
                        .isEmpty(et3.getText().toString())))
                || ((TextUtils.isEmpty(et1.getText().toString()) & TextUtils
                        .isEmpty(et4.getText().toString())))
                || ((TextUtils.isEmpty(et2.getText().toString()) & TextUtils
                        .isEmpty(et3.getText().toString())))
                || ((TextUtils.isEmpty(et2.getText().toString()) & TextUtils
                        .isEmpty(et4.getText().toString())))
                || ((TextUtils.isEmpty(et4.getText().toString()) & TextUtils
                        .isEmpty(et3.getText().toString())))) {
            return;
        }

        num1 = Double.parseDouble(et1.getText().toString());
        num2 = Double.parseDouble(et2.getText().toString());
        num3 = Double.parseDouble(et3.getText().toString());
        num4 = Double.parseDouble(et4.getText().toString());

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.calculate:
            if ((TextUtils.isEmpty(et1.getText().toString()))) {
                res = (num2 * num3) / num4;

                editText.setText(" " + res);
            } else if ((TextUtils.isEmpty(et2.getText().toString()))) {
                res = (num1 * num4) / num3;

                EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);
                editText.setText(" " + res);

            } else if ((TextUtils.isEmpty(et3.getText().toString()))) {
                res = (num4 * num1) / num2;

                EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et3);
                editText.setText(" " + res);
            } else if ((TextUtils.isEmpty(et4.getText().toString()))) {
                res = (num2 * num3) / num1;

                EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et4);
                editText.setText(" " + res);
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat output:

```
11-11 19:05:22.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1911): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-11 19:05:22.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1911): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
11-11 19:05:22.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1911):     at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
11-11 19:05:22.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1911):     at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:248)
11-11 19:05:22.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1911):     at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
11-11 19:05:22.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1911):     at com.example.easyphysics.motolineare.onClick(motolineare.java:73)
11-11 19:05:22.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1911):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
11-11 19:05:22.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1911):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
11-11 19:05:22.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1911):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-11 19:05:22.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1911):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-11 19:05:22.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1911):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-11 19:05:22.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1911):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-11 19:05:22.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1911):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-11 19:05:22.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1911):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-11 19:05:22.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1911):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-11 19:05:22.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1911):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-11 19:05:22.130: E/AndroidRuntime(1911):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-11 19:05:25.371: E/Trace(1932): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set multiple editext to make aout put and input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912805/how-can-i-set-multiple-editext-to-make-aout-put-and-input)

Comment: Please don't create a new, duplicate post. Instead, edit your original post to include things asked for such as code in this case

Comment: ok, sorry, i'll delete the other question... the issue persists howevere...

Comment: I'm sure it does as you haven't even explained what the problem is yet.

Comment: We are getting closer! Can you post the logcat from the crash?

Comment: and now there's the logcat too, the activity is callede "motolineare"

Comment: See my answer. It should explain the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input from the `EditText` is either empty or contains some spaces.
Instead of

```
num1 = Double.parseDouble(et1.getText().toString());
```

You might use:

```
String s = etN.getText().toString().trim();
numN = s.isEmpty()? Double.NaN:Double.parseDouble(s);
```

Replace `N` in `etN` and `numN` with 1..4. You can replace `Double.NaN`with whichever the meaning of an empty field might has.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of these

```
  num1 = Double.parseDouble(et1.getText().toString());
  num2 = Double.parseDouble(et2.getText().toString());
  num3 = Double.parseDouble(et3.getText().toString());
  num4 = Double.parseDouble(et4.getText().toString());
```

is empty when you try to do the calculation on it. Whichever is at line 73 is causing the problem.. Instead of all of those conditions, or even with them, it might be easier to have a `try/catch`. Something like

```
try
{
     res= (num2*num3)/num4;
}
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
    // display a message saying that the box is empty
}
```

but you could probably wrap the whole thing in a `try/catch`.

Comment: one of the edit text must be empty and its text must be ste by the math made from the others, but still it doesn't work

Comment: Ok, but in my above code, `num1`, `num2`, and `num4` cannot be empty or you will get the exception. What is at line 73?

Comment: the problem was the "empty ecception", however thank you for the "stack Overflow tutoral" ;)

Comment: Yes, that's what I told you the exception meant from the beginning. And you are welcome for the "tutorial". I'm sure you won't make the same mistakes